# .htaccess redirect samplesitex.com to samplesitey/alias-page in both https and http variants

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I am trying to redirect an alias url to a different url path. (it wont let me do this in cpanel for some reason)

Example:
SiteX.com > SiteY.com/this-page

### I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitex.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitey.com/this-page $1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

At the moment I can only work out to redirect sitex.com to sitey.com

Everything I try wont let me point to SiteY.com/this-page

So the result is that SiteX after redirect just goes to the base url for SiteY.com

I am sure its very easy to achieve but all answers I find are regarding sub folders and not url-friendly sub paths.

Answer (score 0):

You have one mistake in our RewriteRule: `$1` contains the match of your regular expression, in your case the complete request path.

Now, if you want to append it to `https://www.sitey.com/this-page` you have to remove the space, so the correct rule would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitex.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitey.com/this-page$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This would redirect for example https://sitex.com/mypath to https://www.sitey.com/this-page/mypath

If you want to redirect every request to sitex.com to the same page (https://www.sitey.com/this-page), then you have to remove `$1`.

If xou want to redirect https://sitex.com/mypath to https://www.sitey.com/mypath the correct RewriteRule is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitex.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitey.com$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```